# How to move a sprite to other moving sprite actual position?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have two sprites:

```
var player = SKSpriteNode()
var ball = SKSpriteNode()
```

And I want `ball` to move to `player` position, although player is also moving from left to right:

```
var playerMovementRight = SKAction.moveToX(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - playerTexture.size().width / 2, duration: 2)
var playerMovementLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width + playerTexture.size().width , y: 0, duration: 2)
var playerMovement = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([playerMovementRight,playerMovementLeft]))
player.runAction(playerMovement)
```

This is my code for moving `ball` to `player` position :

```
var moveBall = SKAction.moveTo(player.position, duration: 0.06)
```

Finally I "bounce" the ball out of the screen with this code:

```
var ballOut = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height) , duration: 0.05)
```

I run the actions:

```
var shootBall = SKAction.sequence([moveball,ballOut])
player.runAction(shootBall)
```

My problem is that the player is moving and by the time the ball moves to player position the player is in another position, so the ball isn't really moving to the player "actual" position.
Is there a way that the ball goes to the player actual position then "bounce" off the screen?

Comment: Did you try calculating what the player's position would be after the specified time and move the ball sprite there?

Comment: @Mundi no, how can I do that?, can you show a code example?

Comment: As Mundi said you can move the ball to where the player will be. But here's the thing, if your player can move freely and you need the ball to "follow" the player then this can't be done with actions. I'm not sure if your looking for the ball to follow or simply fire and forget.

Comment: @EpicByte I want to fire and forget, if i dont use actions then how can it be done?

Comment: If you want fire and forget then just set the ball to move to where the player is moving using SKActions.

Comment: But that is what Im doing with var moveBall = SKAction.moveTo(player.position, duration: 0.06)

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable and update this variable in `override func update` like:

```
PlayerPositionUpdate = player.position
```

Use the following code where u have your `shootBall`action right now - or somewhere else where it doesn't get called over and over again.. it should only get called once. Or more often, but then you have to remove the other actions before.

```
var moveBall = SKAction.moveTo(PlayerPositionUpdate, duration: 0.06)
let moveBallForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveBall)
ball.runAction(moveBallForever)
```

And then add a if statement like (maybe in `update`too):

```
if ball.intersectsNode(player){
    let ballOut = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height) , duration: 0.05)
    ball.removeAllActions()
    ball.runAction(ballOut)
}
```

Maybe something like this works .. (i couldn't test it) .. Try it out ;-)